# Haggai's "glory of the (second) Temple greater than the first"

Tags: messiah, beis-hamikdash, book-of-haggai

Haggai 2:9 states that God will fill the Second Temple with glory, such that the glory of the Second Temple would surpass that of the First.

Given that the Second Temple was destroyed by the Romans in 70 AD, and what we historically know of the Second Temple (that it was not more spiritually, architecturally or adornment-wise more "glorious" or spectacular than the first, especially given it was a rushed reconstruction under pressure and threat), and the Messianic nature of the prophecies of this, what is the modern day Jewish understanding of the meaning (and fulfillment) of this prophecy, since the notion that the Messiah entered the Second Temple is rejected?

Comment: Can you source these "historical" claims? I was under the impression that after Herod's renovations the Temple was indeed quite "glorious".

Comment: The talmud refers to the height of the walls of the second as being greater (in terms of physical features).

Comment: I'm upset because you have written a question with vague terms and unsupported assumptions, and now are going in circles with us in comments about what you really think and are asking about. A waste of everyone's time. Please [edit] your question to source your assumptions and clarify what it is you think was or was not the case in each temple and what you seek to know.

Comment: I've deleted a whole bunch of comments, because they were getting out of hand. Raphael Rosch, comments that request clarification to the post should (generally) be answered by editing the post to clarify and *not* by further comments.

Comment: @msh210, I will keep that in mind.  Note that the first question by Double AA becomes muddled by the following sentence, hence the subsequent back and forth.

Comment: @msh210 Re: your edits: because this is a question a lot of Christians would have for Jews who do not view this as a Messianic verse. Editing that out makes the question lose its sense and purpose. A Messianic reading of the text renders the answer obvious: the glory of the Second Temple is greater because it hosted the Messiah. Without that, the answer is then not obvious and at least I for one would like to know what is the currently held view, with sources.

Comment: Re my edit: I did not know Christians read the verse that way. If that was your reason for asking, by all mans edit it back in. But I really think the question makes more sense without it. "The verse says 'it'll be greater'. How?" is a reasonable question. But "The verse says 'it'll be greater'. Christianity says it'll be greater thusly.... Judaism doesn't. How, then will it be greater?" makes no sense unless you can substantiate that Judaism doesn't; and even then the extra comparison to Christianity doesn't add anything to the question.

Comment: Ok, I have rolled back the changes. From a Christian perspective, there are many such verses that we wonder why they are not just plainly understood the way we understand it. It is therefore quite helpful for us to understand modern Jewish views on such things and aids in dispelling assumptions we tend to make for lack of knowledge. I think it also aids in having a better inter-faith relationship. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: I also tried to phrase it in as neutral a tone (in terms of assumptions) as I possibly could for that very reason.

Comment: "the Messianic nature of the prophecies of this" What? Can you provide support for this claim? There is no obvious reason it should be a given that there prophecies are Messianic. Please [edit] in support. cc @msh210

Comment: @DoubleAA If you want to continue discussion, please do so in chat.

Comment: @RaphaelRosch I don't want to continue discussion. I want you to edit in support for your claims. That's a valid reason for the above comment. Please do so. It would make the post better and make it smell less of missionising.  (It doesn't really matter if you are doing that or not; including extra messianic references and references to Jesus on a site about Judaism without explanation smells of missionising. Please add context and support for those claims.)

Comment: @RaphaelRosch I was just rereading your question and I wonder what translation of the text you are using that has the phrase "fill the Second Temple with glory". My text reads "The glory of this last House shall be greater than the first one". The assessment of "greater" is not the same as "fill with."

Comment: and the text never says "second" it says "this last one" more than the first.

Comment: @Danno you have to read verse 7 as well (your Chabad link --is that JPS?-- has "fill with" as well). I will edit when I have time. But I have to say, I am really getting the feeling these have been downvoted in bad faith.

Comment: @RaphaelRosch you should edit the question then as the question makes the claim that this occurs in 2:9, not 2:7.

Comment: @RaphaelRosch Chabad uses the Judaica Press translation, not JPS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_English_Bible_translations#Judaica_Press

Answer (score 5):

Rashi quotes the machlokes between Rav and Shmuel whether it was the physical plant or the number of years that the second temple existed. While some people say that Chagai means to hint about the temple to be built by the mashiach, most say that this refers to the second temple which was about to be built (since Chagai, Zechariah, and Malachi were part of the Anshe Knesses Hagedolah) and that before it would be destroyed, this is what it would become.

Note that Rashi comments on the phrase "will be greater". That is Rashi says that Rav holds that the actual temple itself (after Herod rebuilt it) was "more magnificent" than the first temple. Shmuel holds that the "greater glory" was that it lasted longer. Both speak of it even though it did not have the same spiritual glory as the first temple.

The fame of the temple spread throughout the Roman Empire which could also mean that the glory "was greater" in that it was a major attraction over much of the known world.

[Chagai 2:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16204/jewish/Chapter-2.htm#v=9&showrashi=true)

> ט גָּדוֹל יִהְיֶה כְּבוֹד הַבַּיִת הַזֶּה הָאַחֲרוֹן מִן הָרִאשׁוֹן
>   אָמַר יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת וּבַמָּקוֹם הַזֶּה אֶתֵּן שָׁלוֹם נְאֻם יְהֹוָה
>   צְבָאוֹת:
>
> 9 The glory of this last House shall be greater than the first one,
>   said the Lord of Hosts. And in this place I will grant peace, says the
>   Lord of Hosts.
>
> Rashi: shall be greater: There was a controversy between Rav and
>   Samuel. One said: In the building; and one said: In the years, that
>   the years of the First Temple were four hundred and ten, and those of
>   the Second Temple were four hundred and twenty.

The Jewish Virtual Library says that not only was it a magnificent building, but that multitudes came to see it. I have seen references that not only Jews, but nonJews from all over the Roman Empire came to see the temple.

[The Second Temple](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/History/secondtemple.html)

> The Second Temple was not only awe inspiring because of its religious
>   significance, but also for its physical dimensions, its grandeur and
>   its beauty. Thus, as the Roman generals sat surveying Jerusalem and
>   considering the Temple’s future they hesitated before ordering its
>   destruction. Jews, from that day to this, have yearned and prayed for
>   its rebuilding, and tourists and religious people alike have come to
>   behold the site on which it once stood.
>
> Normally a city of 100 to 200 thousand people, three times a year on
>   the pilgrim festivals of Passover, Pentecost and Tabernacles,
>   Jerusalem’s population swelled to 1 million souls (the exact number
>   depending on the source of population estimates). On these occasions
>   this small ancient city had to cope not only with the throng of people
>   but also their sacrificial animals and offerings, necessitating
>   temporary increases in food supplies, accommodation, ritual bathing
>   facilities, and all aspects of commerce. It was Herod, installed by
>   the Romans as governor of Jerusalem, who faced these logistical
>   problems, and who consequently set about renovating the city and the
>   Temple to accommodate this massive periodic influx.
>
> Before work began on the Temple, Herod spent eight years stockpiling
>   materials for its construction. Then, a workforce of over 10,000 men
>   began its construction including a contingent of 1,500 specially
>   trained priests who were the only ones permitted to work on the
>   innermost and holiest parts of the Temple. Building continued for a
>   further twenty years, though the Temple was in a sufficiently ready
>   state within three and a half years of its commencement to be
>   dedicated.